# Locations in range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Location model where each location has a lat and lon coordinate in degrees, I am trying to have a Location instance return all Locations within range of a specified distance based on http://www.mullie.eu/geographic-searches/:

```
  def in_range(distance)
    earth_radius = 3958.75587

    maxlat = self.lat + to_deg(distance / earth_radius)
    minlat = self.lat - to_deg(distance / earth_radius)
    maxlon = self.lon + to_deg(distance / earth_radius / Math::cos(to_rad(self.lat)))
    minlon = self.lon - to_deg(distance / earth_radius / Math::cos(to_rad(self.lat)))

    Location.where("lat > ? AND lat < ? AND lon > ? AND lon < ?",minlat,maxlat,minlon,maxlon)
  end
```

When I create a location and request a range:

```
l1 = Location.find_by_post_code("SW11")
```

this returns a lat of 51.4663 and a lon of -0.165543 my maxlat,minlat,maxlon,minlon values are far too small when I request:

```
l1.in_range(10)

maxlat = 51.466344087822264
minlat = 51.46625591217773
maxlon = -0.1654722301720378
minlon = -0.1656137698279622
```

So I think the calculation for these values is wrong but am having trouble finding any more resources on this, does anyone know the correct way to obtain the max and min coordinate values?

---

**Edit - Subsequently answered, the full working code is below:**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  EARTH_RADIUS = 3958.75587

  def in_range(distance)
    maxlat = self.lat + rad2deg(distance / EARTH_RADIUS)
    minlat = self.lat - rad2deg(distance / EARTH_RADIUS)
    maxlon = self.lon + rad2deg(distance / EARTH_RADIUS / Math.cos(deg2rad(self.lat)))
    minlon = self.lon - rad2deg(distance / EARTH_RADIUS / Math.cos(deg2rad(self.lat)))

    locations = Location.where("lat > ? AND lat < ? AND lon > ? AND lon < ?",minlat,maxlat,minlon,maxlon).to_a
    locations.each do |location|
      if self.distance_to(location) > distance
        locations.delete(location)
      end
    end
    locations
  end

  def distance_to(location)
    lat_source_rad = deg2rad(self.lat)
    lat_destination_rad = deg2rad(location.lat)
    lat_delta = deg2rad(location.lat - self.lat)
    lon_delta = deg2rad(location.lon - self.lon)

    a = Math::sin(lat_delta/2.0) * Math::sin(lat_delta/2.0) +
        Math::cos(lat_source_rad) * Math::cos(lat_destination_rad) *
        Math::sin(lon_delta/2.0) * Math::sin(lon_delta/2.0)
    b = 2 * Math::atan2(Math::sqrt(a), Math::sqrt(1.0-a))
    c = EARTH_RADIUS * b
  end

  private

  def rad2deg(rad)
    rad / Math::PI * 180.0
  end

  def deg2rad(deg)
    deg / 180.0 * Math::PI
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies on the code you didn't post, specifically, the `to_deg` and `to_rad` method. Maybe you have wrote integer division instead of float division somewhere in the two methods? Note that `3/2==1` but `3/2.0==1.5` in Ruby.

```
class Location
  RADIUS = 3958.75587
  attr_accessor :lat, :lng

  def initialize(lat, lng)
    @lat = lat
    @lng = lng
  end

  def ranges(distance)
    maxlat = @lat + rad2deg(distance / RADIUS)
    minlat = @lat - rad2deg(distance / RADIUS)

    maxlng = @lng + rad2deg(distance / RADIUS / Math.cos(deg2rad(@lat)))
    minlng = @lng - rad2deg(distance / RADIUS / Math.cos(deg2rad(@lat)))

    [[minlat, maxlat], [minlng, maxlng]]
  end

  private
  def rad2deg(rad)
    rad / Math::PI * 180.0
  end

  def deg2rad(deg)
    deg / 180.0 * Math::PI
  end
end

l = Location.new(51.4663, -0.165543)
p l.ranges(10)
#=> [
#     [51.32156821710003, 51.611031782899964],
#     [-0.39786664062357346, 0.06678064062357347]
#   ]
```

Comment: Brilliant, I have added the correctly amended code that works, thank you so much!